# LowerCase and UpperCase Alternating c#

Tags: c#, uppercase, lowercase, alternating

I need convert a phrase words in uppercase and lowercase continuous (alternating).

Example.

Input:
`the girl is pretty.`

Output:
`tHe GiRl Is PrEtTy`

I have tried the code below but it only convert the first letter:

```
char[] array = texto.ToCharArray();
if (array.Length >= 1)
{
    if (char.IsLower(array[0]))
    {
        array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
    }
}
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (array[i - 1] == ' ')
    {
        if (char.IsLower(array[i]))
        {
            array[i] = char.ToUpper(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
return new string(array);
```

Thanks

Comment: I try,

char[] array = texto.ToCharArray();
            if (array.Length >= 1)
            {
                if (char.IsLower(array[0]))
                {
                    array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
                }
            }         
            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array[i - 1] == ' ')
                {
                    if (char.IsLower(array[i]))
                    {
                        array[i] = char.ToUpper(array[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return new string(array);

Comment: but Only convert the first letter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fancy solution using LINQ:

```
string someString = "the girl is pretty";
string newString = string.Concat(
    someString.ToLower().AsEnumerable().Select((c, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? c : char.ToUpper(c)));
```

This basically does the following:

1. Convert the string to lowercase.
2. Iterate over each character.
3. Convert every second character to upper case.
4. Join the characters into a single string.

A more “classical” solution could look like this:

```
string someString = "the girl is pretty";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool uppercase = false;
foreach (char c in someString)
{
    if (uppercase)
        sb.Append(char.ToUpper(c));
    else
        sb.Append(char.ToLower(c));

    uppercase = !uppercase;
}

string newString = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Like the lambda/modulus solution! That's slick!

Comment: @poke You could use `String.Concat` instead of `String.Join`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by `poke` was right, however it includes the spaces on alternating the case. I do some tweak to the previous answer, it ignores the spaces of the string.

```
string someString = "the girl is pretty";
string space = " ";

char[] str = someString.ToCharArray();
char[] str2 = space.ToCharArray();

bool uppercase = false;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char c in str)
{
    if (c != str2[0])
    {
        if (uppercase)
            sb.Append(char.ToUpper(c));
        else
        {
            sb.Append(char.ToLower(c));
        }
        uppercase = !uppercase;
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(c);
    }   
}

string newString = sb.ToString();
```